# How to write GCP cloud API implementation for network, storage and compute

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am writing a client for GCP Golang sdk APIs for network, storage and compute. I need help with the right sequence of calls.

Is below code the right way to create the disks? Is there any efficient way of writing this code.

`disk := new(compute.Disk)
operation, e := service.Disks.Insert(project, zone, disk).Do()`

What are these other constructs like - 
DisksInsertCall etc.. Are they more efficient for bulk disk creation?

I am using library https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/. This does not give me proper parameters and sequence needed for creating an instance or a disk.

Also what is faster way creating bulk virtual machines and disks?
1. using deployment manager OR
2. making direct API calls using go routines

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/ https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/concepts

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to GCP official APIs and [Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library). In this case you need [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/)

To create an instance you need to use the [method instance.insert](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert) you can try the API with the link I provided at the bottom of this link there are examples in the most popular computer languagues supported by GCP Client Libraries. To add more parameters with the "Try this API" UI just click on the + symbol

Below are is my Request body used with this UI that works

```
{
  "kind": "compute#instance",
  "name": "new-instance-1",
  "zone": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-f",
  "machineType": "projects/xxxxxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
  "displayDevice": {
    "enableDisplay": false
  },
  "metadata": {
    "kind": "compute#metadata",
    "items": []
  },
  "tags": {
    "items": []
  },
  "disks": [
    {
      "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
      "type": "PERSISTENT",
      "boot": true,
      "mode": "READ_WRITE",
      "autoDelete": true,
      "deviceName": "new-instance-1",
      "initializeParams": {
        "sourceImage": "projects/eip-images/global/images/debian-9-drawfork-v20191004",
        "diskType": "projects/xxxxxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-f/diskTypes/pd-standard",
        "diskSizeGb": "10"
      },
      "diskEncryptionKey": {}
    }
  ],
  "canIpForward": false,
  "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
      "subnetwork": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default",
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
          "name": "External NAT",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
          "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
        }
      ],
      "aliasIpRanges": []
    }
  ],
  "description": "",
  "labels": {},
  "scheduling": {
    "preemptible": false,
    "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
    "automaticRestart": true,
    "nodeAffinities": []
  },
  "deletionProtection": false,
  "reservationAffinity": {
    "consumeReservationType": "ANY_RESERVATION"
  },
  "serviceAccounts": [
    {
      "email": "1060078476845-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
      ]
    }
```

Now moving into storage there are many types suck as disks and buckets, I will assume you are refering to disks with my previous command a boot disk is created during the creation of the instance and you can add multiple disks during the creation.

Here is the [method to create just a disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/insert) , to attach an existing disk to an instance use the [instances.attachDisk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/attachDisk) method. Again if you specified multiple disks during the creation time you may skip this paragraph

> > Also what is faster way creating bulk virtual machines and disks?

It will depend on your preferences, you may use both but personally I like to use the [gcloud commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) from the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/).